# Can we convert an Android Studio project for Unity3D?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

May be this question not fit here, but I didn't find any other medium to ask. I have a project in Android studio or eclipse, I want to open in unity.. because I don't want to rewrite again in unity.. any help or suggestion..

Comment: I highly doubt there's a conversion tool :p you will have to rewrite it in unity

Answer (score 1):

As i know they are two different compilers and you can't convert their projects to each other.maybe you can just copy some code if needed but work spaces are separate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done, because both things are different libraries too (as one of the errors).